# Reading properties in parent maven pom.xml

Tags: maven

I am reading properties from a file, in maven using:

```
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <phase>initialize</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <files>
                             <file>${project.parent.basedir}/jenkins/version.properties</file>
                         </files>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
```

pom.xmls contained in sub-projects are using the properties pulled from the properties file as follows:

```
           <manifestEntries>
               <Built-Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Built-Date>
               <Version>${VERSION}B${BUILD_NUMBER}</Version>
           </manifestEntries>
```

The problem is that when they call project.parent.basedir, they are not using the parent project, they are looking for the version.properties file in the directory above the parent. Any ideas as to how I might make them use the right directory? I can't use project.basedir, because then they will look in their own project directory for the file, which is not correct either.

Comment: Does it work using `${project.basedir}` ?

Comment: no, because the child project the looks for the jenkins directory in its own directory, whereas it should look in the parent.